# Rename all columns with characters

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to rename all columns in my data.frame. Right now, they are numbered 1-150 (without the X) but I would like to add "id" before each number.

Right now:

```
    c = data.frame(1, 2)
    names(c)[1] <- "1"
    names(c)[2] <- "2"
```

What I want: so that it is `id1`, `id2` as each column name.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try `paste0('id_', names(df))`

Comment: Avoid using `c` as varname, it is a function in R. Read about `make.names`, and `paste`. Something like: `colnames(DF) <- paste0("id", colnames(DF))` should work.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: `colnames(c) <- gsub("X","id",colnames(c))` or `colnames(c) <- sapply(1:ncol(c), function(k) paste0("id", toString(k)))` can get you there

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dplyr::rename_all()`

```r
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
  rename_all(~ paste0("id_", .x)) %>% 
  names()
```

or with base R

```r
setNames(
  iris, 
  nm = paste0(
    "id_", names(iris)
  )
) %>% names()
```

Comment: Please avoid answering duplicates, kindly search for existing posts before answering.